# SQLAlchemy bulk insert statement in Postgres database throws AttributeError

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2, bulkinsert

I am trying to insert rows in Python SQLAlchemy by bulk into a Postgres database by using an `insert` statement. I need to use the insert statement instead of `bulk_insert_mappings`, as I want to silently ignore failed insertion of duplicate entries. This was not apparent before, but I have added it now.

The table is created as it should. However, even a very simple insert operation via statement API throws this error:

```
AttributeError: '_NoResultMetaData' object has no attribute '_indexes_for_keys'
```

Minimal Verifiable Example:

```
import os

import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import (
    Column,
    INTEGER,
    TEXT
)
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import insert
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

Base = declarative_base()


class Test(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'test'
    id = Column(INTEGER, primary_key=True)
    data = Column(TEXT)


engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(os.environ['DATABASE_CONNECTION'])
Session = sessionmaker(engine)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine, Base.metadata.tables.values(), checkfirst=True)

connection = engine.connect()
buffer = [
    {
        'data': "First test"
    },
    {
        'data': "Second test"
    }
]

insert_statement = insert(Test).values(buffer)
# Using insert statement instead of bulk_insert_mappings so I can do nothing when adding duplicate entries
insert_or_do_nothing = insert_statement.on_conflict_do_nothing(index_elements=[Company.local_id])
orm_statement = sqlalchemy.select(Test).from_statement(insert_or_do_nothing)

with Session() as session:
    session.execute(orm_statement).scalars()

connection.close()
```

Full stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/project/path/test.py", line 41, in <module>
    session.execute(orm_statement).scalars()
  File "/venv/path/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1715, in execute
    result = compile_state_cls.orm_setup_cursor_result(
  File "/venv/path/sqlalchemy/orm/context.py", line 354, in orm_setup_cursor_result
    return loading.instances(result, querycontext)
  File "/venv/path/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 89, in instances
    cursor.close()
  File "/venv/path/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "/venv/path/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 208, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/venv/path/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 69, in instances
    *[
  File "/venv/path/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 70, in <listcomp>
    query_entity.row_processor(context, cursor)
  File "/venv/path/sqlalchemy/orm/context.py", line 2627, in row_processor
    _instance = loading._instance_processor(
  File "/venv/path/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 715, in _instance_processor
    primary_key_getter = result._tuple_getter(pk_cols)
  File "/venv/path/sqlalchemy/engine/result.py", line 934, in _tuple_getter
    return self._metadata._row_as_tuple_getter(keys)
  File "/venv/path/sqlalchemy/engine/result.py", line 106, in _row_as_tuple_getter
    indexes = self._indexes_for_keys(keys)
AttributeError: '_NoResultMetaData' object has no attribute '_indexes_for_keys'
```

Am I misusing the statement interface? The ORM statement looks fine:

```
INSERT INTO test (data) VALUES (:data_m0), (:data_m1)
```

I am using

- PostgreSQL 14.4
- psycopg2-binary 2.9.3
- SQLAlchemy 1.4.39

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that uses insert statement: Avoid using the ORM statements. For some reason, using plain statements seems to do the job, whilst ORM ones throw the `AttributeError`.

This is confusing, as [the official documentation calls for ORM statements](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/persistence_techniques.html?highlight=insert#using-postgresql-on-conflict-with-returning-to-return-upserted-orm-objects):

```
# THIS APPROACH DID NOT WORK FOR ME

stmt = stmt.on_conflict_do_update(
    index_elements=[User.name], set_=dict(fullname=stmt.excluded.fullname)
).returning(User)

orm_stmt = (
    select(User)
    .from_statement(stmt)
    .execution_options(populate_existing=True)
)
for user in session.execute(
    orm_stmt,
).scalars():
    print("inserted or updated: %s" % user)
```

But if you omit the ORM statement part, all is good

```
# THIS WORKS

insert_statement = insert(Test).values(buffer)
insert_or_do_nothing = insert_statement.on_conflict_do_nothing(index_elements=[Test.id])

    with Session() as session:
        session.execute(insert_or_do_nothing)
        session.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/persistence_techniques.html#usage) you could try to use `session.bulk_insert_mappings()`.

```
buffer = [
    {
        'data': "First test"
    },
    {
        'data': "Second test"
    }
]


with Session() as session:
    session.bulk_insert_mappings(Test, buffer)
```

Comment: Hey Shane, thank you for your answer! I actually need to use the `insert` statement and cannot use  `bulk_insert_mappings`, as my insert logic should be able to ignore inserting duplicate rows. I have eventually found a solution (see my answer), but would love to hear your comments or alternative solutions, if you have any!